# How to find optimal parameter for Adaptivethreshold in opencv Python?

Tags: python, opencv, adaptive-threshold

I'm learning adaptivethreshold technique, I'm wondering is there any calculation for choosing blocksize and constant C (which are parameters of adaptivethreshold function), or I just find the optimal values by iterating each number?